# Javascript - Remove hidden fields or set to empty before form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

---

I want to either remove 2 hidden fields or set them to null in a form before a POST action is performed using onclick event on a checkbox.

This is what I have -

```
<input type="hidden" id="ci" name="ci" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" id="pg" name="pg" value="prev"/>

<form:checkboxes path="choices" items="${lookups}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="label" element="li" **onclick="this.form.submit();"**/>
```

How do I modify my onclick event JS to support this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change the `onclick` to this:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('ci').value = ''; document.getElementById('pg').value = ''; this.form.submit();"
```

You just have to use the ID of the elements then assign their value to empty string - this will still send value though. To disable any value, disable those elements:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('ci').disabled = true; document.getElementById('pg').disabled = true; this.form.submit();"
```

Answer (score 3):

`$("input[type='hidden']").each(function(){`

```
  $(this).reset();
```

`});`

.......................................................or......................................................

The below code is made up of javascript. This may work

`oForm = getElementById('form_id');`

`var frm_elements = oForm.elements;`

`for (i = 0; i < frm_elements.length; i++)`

`{`

```
field_type = frm_elements[i].type.toLowerCase();
switch (field_type)
{
case "text":
case "password":
case "textarea":
case "hidden":
    frm_elements[i].value = "";
    break;
case "radio":
case "checkbox":
case "select-one":
case "select-multi":
default:
}
```

`}`

Comment: Thats JQuery. I think he wants plain JS.

Comment: You don't need a switch statement when hidden fields are the only ones of interest, but if you are going to use one you need a break statement _before_ the hidden case or it will also clear all the types listed above that. Regarding your jquery, are you sure it has a reset method? (If so can you please provide a link to the doco?)

Comment: @nnnnnn [link](http://api.jquery.com/reset-selector/) This is the link for jquery doc -> forms -> reset method.

Comment: That link is for the ":reset" selector. I don't believe there is a reset method.

Answer (score -1):

Make onclick call a function which calls submit. Using jQuery is easy to do this

```
function doform(){
    $.each($('input[type=hidden]'), function(input){
        $(input).val('');
    });
 }
```

Modify your onclick to call that. You can also do it through normal DOM access using getElementsByTagName and filtering on type or even a straight set of calls to getElementById

```
function doform(){
  var i1 = document.getElementById('pg');
  i1.value = '';
  var i2 = document.getElementById('ci');
  i2.value = '';
 }
```

Comment: $('input[type="hidden"]').val(''); - you don't need .each()

Comment: Even easier. I didn't know jquery would apply a function to a set of matched nodes implicitly.

Answer (score -1):

Change your onclick part like below.

```
onclick="javascript:Clicked();"
```

Then define your onclick function in clientside javascript under head tags.

```
<Head>
<script language=javascript>
function Clicked()
{
 //1. Write code to hide fields
 document.forms[0].submit(); 
}
</script>
</Head>
```

Comment: That doesn't show him how to actually hide or nullify the fields which is part of the question. Also you don't need language=javascript when you generate a script tag.

Comment: @tkone I was just explaning the basic structure for him to get started. Though it is not needed to put the javascript tags its a standard to be followed as you can put many types of inline scripts. regarding nullifying the fields the answer has been already provided above.